# Accessing downloaded file instead of page HTML

Tags: c#, http, webclient

I have some code that connects to an HTTP API, and is supposed to get an XML response. When the API link is placed in a browser, the browser downloads the XML as a file. However, when the code connects to the same API, HTML is returned. I've told the API owner but they don't think anything is wrong. Is there a way to capture the downloaded file instead of the HTML?

I've tried setting the headers to make my code look like a browser. Also tried using WebRequest instead of WebClient. But nothing works.

Here is the code, the URL works in the browser (file downloaded) but doesn't work for WebClient:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

The code should somehow get the XML file instead of the page HTML (actually the HTML doesn't appear in the browser, only the file).

Comment: can you show us the returned html result? you can anonymize the included urls

Comment: The HTML is rather long, too long to post here. But it seems to just be the front page of the website that the API belongs to. It doesn't have any references to the API within it.

Answer (score 0):

The uri that you access may be a HTML page that have its own mechanism (like generating the actual download address which may be dynamically generated by the server and redirecting to it, in order to prevent external linking access) to access the real file.

It is supposed to use a browser background browser core like [CefSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen/) to run the HTML and its javascript to let it navigate, and probably you may want to hook the download event to handle the downloading.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no HTML on the page when the URL is accessed in the browser. It just downloads the XML file directly.. so it doesn't seem that running the HTML is an option.

Comment: The redirection may takes place in the server side application only on receiving HTTP request headers that identifies the agent as a browser, which is also supposed to be resolved by using a browser core.

Comment: Or there is an HTML page that exists for a very short moment and redirected to the file when you are accessing it via a browser.

Comment: Any way, no matter what mechanism the site actually uses, as long as it works on browsers, it would work on a browser embeded in your applicatoin

Comment: Thanks. I tried to embed WebBrowser but it didn't work because it's not a single thread apartment application (it's a C# class library).. thing is, this API used to work without issues so I think the vendor changed something but they think that they haven't :(

Comment: WebBrowser is a part of Windows Forms so it is supposed to avoid it since it unless you are sure that the application that uses your class library targets .NET Framework or .NET Core 3.0+ only on windows. But you can use Cef that was mentioned in the answer.

Comment: It is OK for your class library to reference another class library, as long as the referenced library targets commonly.

Comment: Additionally, I remember that WebBrowser control must be hosted within the main thread, but other alternatives may have no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `accept` header to the `WebClient` object.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
  client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/xml;q=1"; 
  string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. In the end, it was caused by our vendor switching to TLS 1.2. I just had to force my code to use 1.2 and then it worked.